# Ошибка при создании таблицы в SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle 11g 
Создаю таблицу с помощью команды: `CREATE TABLE RAZMER_SHTAF ( STATYA VARCHAR2(10) PRIMARY KEY, VID_NARUSH VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL, RAZMER_SHTRAF NUMBERS(10));`

В результате выдаёт ошибку: "ORA-+00907: отсутствует правая скобка"
В других таблицах нет связей с данной. В чём может быть проблема ?

Comment: В Oracle нет типа данных `NUMBERS`, может вы имели ввиду `NUMBER`, думаю это решит проблему

Comment: Да, это помогло. Спасибо за помощь.